# PHP image upload Android/iOS images are in landscape

Tags: php, android, ios, image, upload

I wrote a script to upload images with AJAX and PHP.
The script works well but there is the following problem:
If I upload an image from an Android device that was shot in portrait it is uploaded in landscape.

Is there a way to fix this?
The problem is that I cant rotate all images because uploaded images from desktops are uploaded right.

Comment: You should of course rotate the image before sending.

Comment: And how can i  accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Well this is new. Uploading photos from smartphones not possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420548/well-this-is-new-uploading-photos-from-smartphones-not-possible)